Vuetify time-picker change minutes to multiples of 3
Is it possible to dynamically adjust the Vuetify time picker to display minutes in a series such as  of 3(e.g.: 3, 6, 9), based on data retrieved from a database? The data from the database will determine whether the time picker should display multiples of 3 or the standard multiples of 5.

is it possible to do it statically? if not, then you won't get much luck doing it dymanically

You need to set minuteStep based on the data retrieved. Then, bind this minuteStep to the v-time-picker's minute-interval prop to dynamically adjust the minute intervals displayed by the time picker.
